# Bug in the search implementation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search

I just noticed that searching for `terminator` (a well known terminal emulator) also returns hits for `terminal`:

[image]

As you can see in the image above, `terminal` is highlighted as though it were a hit. It works as expected if I quote `"terminator"` but that shouldn't be necessary. I am guessing there is some kind of magic going on behind the scenes that assumes that I mistyped terminator and actually meant terminal but it seems like more of a bug than a feature if so.

Comment: I checked the tags' synonyms, and they don't appear to be linked by that.

Comment: I might be wrong on this one, waiting for Nick to chime in here.

Comment: @TimPost stemming explains the behavior to me. I still think this is a case where it is a bug rather than a feature but I am well aware of how useful stemming is in general so I have no problem with your answer. I already know I can avoid it through quoting so as long as you guys are aware of it, I'm pretty much satisfied.